# How to add styles .css files from .angular-cli.json into karma unit test

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid v.17 and in order for it to show the grid correctly, I had to import ag-grid .css in .angular-cli.json, but when I'm creating a testBed in karma unit test, how can I add those css files?

styles I added in .angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "styles/app.scss",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/compiled-icons.css"
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it inside your `karma.config.js` file

```
files: [
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
  "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/compiled-icons.css",
  { pattern: './src/app.scss', watched: true,  included: true, served: true }
],
preprocessors: {
  './src/styles.scss': ['scss']
},
```

You might also have to add preprocessors for karma

```
npm install karma-scss-preprocessor node-sass --save-dev
```

Reference: [How to configure Karma to include global scss files for an angular-cli project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44460733/1417185)

Another reference: [Angular 4 Karma Loading CSS in Unit Testing](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/08/05/angular-4-karma-loading-css-in-unit-testing/)